# How to check string variable in if condition?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have string variable, here how to check the name dynamically, because the value of string name is dynamic.

```
string name;
if(studentname==.............)          
{

}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, could you rewrite it with a more clear example what you need?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
String.Compare(name, studentname)
```

[source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbh501kz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
    String name; 
    if(studentname==name) {

    }
```